# Admob Interstitial launches after page(activity) load

Tags: android, admob

I implemented Admob Interstitial ad as per following link,

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

The problem for this implementation is that the interstitial ads are not shown between the activities. On click of list it will go to next activity and after 1-2 second ad shows. Which breaks the Admob policy.

So how can I implement the code in such a way that ad shows between the activities.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

        // set the ad unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the ad loading and the ad presentation in order to avoid ad display on unwanted time.

What you are doing is loading the ad in the time when you actually want to show the ad

first load the ad at start of the activity:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this); 
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ID");
AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest1);
```

When you want to display the ad - check for availability and display if its loaded:

```
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
```

That way the ad will display immediately without delay

I Recommend you put the loading code in your firstActivity and when user click to go to SecondActivity run the interstitial.show() code

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your first activity, and put `showInterstitial();` in the OnClick of the item that is launching the second activity. `showInterstitial()` should be the first thing done in the OnClick, then launch the next activity.

You can then get rid of this entire section:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            showInterstitial();
        }
    });
```

The ad will load in that background, since you are loading the ad in onCreate (like you are supposed to) and the ad should be ready by the time the user clicks the item to move to the next activity. If it's not ready yet, it simply won't display.